# Adding original color icon the React-Icons

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js13, react-icons

Here's my code snippet:

```
<div className="mt-6 flex gap-2">
    <AuthSocialButton
        icon={BsGithub}
        onClick={() => socialAction('github')}
    />
    <AuthSocialButton
        icon={BsGoogle}
        onClick={() => socialAction('google')}
    />
</div>
```

React-icons itself only have a blank gray color. Is there any way for React-icons to have the colors of the original logos that it copied from? For example, The react icon google looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/25A0v.png
I want it to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZd9Y.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add inline style or CSS classes ?
something like that?

```
<AuthSocialButton
icon={<BsGithub style={{ color: '#333' }} />}  // GitHub's color
onClick={() => socialAction('github')}/>
```

Comment: No I mean not one logo color, I mean the original logo colors, for example the Google logo consists of many different colors, not just one background color